# Lacking Django knowledge

Tags: django

I'm been trying to learn django and become proficient at it but at the moment , i'm struggling at making django app. I have consume knowledge of through the Google python classes and django book from chapter 1 to 7 . Then I tried to jump into lightbird django example but it's proven to be hard . I can't even do the first app.

Can you help me get back on track by pointing me to the right direction.
Should I master python before coming into django? or I should go through making django apps and pick up the bit and pieces.

Any great Resource?

Comment: Have you taken the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)?

Comment: I done that and I under that

Comment: Well, we have the same situation before. I just did, I search for online video tutorial, in that way I learn and understand the basic of django. That basic will be your foundation if you want to push through.

Comment: It's really hard to understand if you just read it, that is usually for a beginner. If you have experience in django, you can understand what you have read and can trace and fixed the problem easily. On the spot tutorial is better than reading (for beginner only)

Comment: I tried to do lightbird django example and it's proven to be very hard for me . I mean , I tried to post question here for help but the answers are unfamiliar to me . I feel like I don't know if i should go lefft or right.

Comment: ok thank you cathy . I will go back into django videos

Comment: there are many tutorials in youtube... And if you can understand the basic of django you can now go back to lightbird. I forgot try this python tutorial: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/. It is really easy to understand. (Python before Django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes it is necessary to learn Python before diving into Django, but there is no need to master it. You need to know how to write classes, create objects, create functions and other things that Python provides such as decorators, tuples, hashes, etc. Once you are flexible with Python scripting it is easy to learn the framework.
- Also while you are reading django book you should refer documentation of Django and read information about the classes you come across. In Django Book information is given on a superficial level, you need to know what functionality each class provides and their importance, and that you can get in documentation.
- There are various video tutorials out there, they teach you to create applications. Again you should read documentation of Django.

Documentation is the best source by which you can learn bits and pieces, internal working of Django applications. Books, and video tutorials will teach you how to integrate your Django knowledge with HTML, Javascript, CSS and other web application stuff. Django book/video tutorials and Documentation is a great combo to master Django.

Here is one link that I referred : http://hackedexistence.com/project-django.html

Comment: thank you very much cathy and verdarthk. this give me alot of hope. I have to close this thread